# Load balancing to expose single port

Tags: tomcat, port, load-balancing, matomo

I have hosted a web server from Apache tomcat. To monitor server analytic, I have created a piwik server. Web server serves on 8080 and piwik(mysql) serves on 9090 port. I need to expose only port 80. So both 8080 and 9090 ports shouldn't expose.

I found below resources,

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

https://github.com/topcloud/loadbalancer

Since I'm new to load balancing, I am unable to how to setup it. Are there any better way to achieve it? If there are any resources that achieve this load balancing issue, please reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure

1. Piwik to run on Apache HTTPD
2. Run your web server on Tomcat
3. Configure HTTPD to [forward](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) requests to Tomcat

Comment: Is there any possible way to do this by Node server instead of HTTPD?

Comment: Yes but you should do it only if you need Node server for anything else.